# Tab key navigation inside Telerik RadGridView

Tags: c#, silverlight, telerik, radgridview, keyboard-navigation

In a Telerik `RadGridView` with a `GroupDescriptor` set, once the focus enters the grid, the focus won't leave by pressing tab. It simply loops back to the beginning of the grid.

That is, there are some controls above and below the grid. When hitting the tab key, focus starts at the top and moves down. It gets to the grid and (as expected and desired) begins to tab through individual cells. When it gets to the last cell, however, hitting tab again moves focus to the first cell. I would expect it to move to the next control below the grid, or the next control in order of `TabIndex` property.

This only happens when a `GroupDescriptor` is set and there are rows in multiple groups. If there is no `GroupDescriptor` or all rows are in the same group, focus moves on as expected. Also of note, this is a grid with `IsReadOnly="True"`. I have tried the different options for the `TabNavigation` property with no success.

What can I do to get the expected behavior? Some property I'm missing? Do I have to implement a custom tab key behavior with Telerik's `KeyboardCommandProvider`, and if so, how?